# What is convert view in adapters Android

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-view, android-recyclerview

I wonder what is convert view ? I understand that it is

> The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this
>   view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not
>   possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method
>   can create a new view. Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of
>   view types, so that this View is always of the right type (see
>   getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int)).

What is this under the hood ?
Is it just simple view inflated earlier ? Or something other ?

Why we cannot use it like this ?

```
if (convertView!=null) {
   return convertView;
}
else {
   return new ......
}
```

Why we have to use setTag method to set reference to the our inflated view ?

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

We are setting one view another view reference as the TAG , why not just to pass it directly as convertView ?
Please help with this question, I can't write any code because cannot understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood speaking you would see that it inflates the views just a couple of times (enough to fill up the screen) as this is really slow. It is as you said reusing the views it had inflated earlier. When you scroll, it just tells you that you need to fill the earlier inflated views with the data appropriate for the current position.

You actually can always return a new view you inflate every time, but this will have a negative impact on your performance and there by scrolling smoothness.

With the `setTag` you are telling it to remember the object which holds information about the view itself (called `ViewHolder`).

Answer (score 0):

> What is this under the hood ? Is it just simple view inflated earlier
>   ? Or something other ?

it is both. In particular is an array of views of the type you inflated. The size of this array is equal to the number of views enough to fill completely your screen. This way you allocate only a constant number of views.

> Why we cannot use it like this ?

```
if (convertView!=null) {
   return convertView;
}
else {
   return new ......
}
```

you still need to fill up your view with the data of your dataset. In the snippet you posted above you aren't doing it. You could do something like

```
if (convertView!=null) {

   // convertView.findVIewById(...)
   // set data to view
   return convertView;
}
else {
   convertView =  new ......
   // convertView.findVIewById(...)
   // set data to view
   return converView;
}
```

> Why we have to use setTag method to set reference to the our inflated
>   view ?

it's called `ViewHolder` pattern, and you are not setting the inflated view, but a small object that contains the inflated's view *component*. This way you can avoid calling `findViewById` every time getView is called and you want to fill up the view with content of your dataset (at position)